# In GWT, how can I make my widget escape the display bounds of its containing widget?

Tags: gwt

So for example, if a context menu was too small for its panel when the menu opened, I should like the menu to spill out of the panel in order to display properly.

In Swing, you can arrange for the widget to render on a 'glass pane' which is a transparent layer in front of 'everything else'.  Is there an equivalent in GWT?

In my case, my 'context menu' is not a classical menu - it's some arbitrary GWT panel, which might contain (for example) a form with some editable fields, more resembling a dialog ... but it isn't modal, and its position needs to be anchored into the surrounding HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT's [PopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) appears to fulfil this role.